# Finding the first transaction date in a data set

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, dataset

So the picture is the data set I'm dealing with. I'm using Python 3 and Pandas pack. Question I'm answering is: "What was the month and day of the first sale? Store as a tuple in that order and assign the tuple to the variable first_date."
[image]

My thought process was turning the 'trans_timestamp' column into int rather than floats so I could find the min value of the int. This is the code I implemented

```
df_cleaned['trans_timestamp'] = df_cleaned['trans_timestamp'].astype(int)

first_date = df_cleaned['trans_timestamp'].min()

first_date
```

I'm guessing either the `.astype(int)` is the problem, or I'm just looking at the problem in a completely different perspective than how they want me too. Anything helps thanks!

Comment: [Why should I not upload images of ... when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question). [Discourage screenshots of code and/or errors](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). [Why not upload images of code on SO  ...?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question).  [You should not post code as an image because:...](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2823755)

Comment: [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Please format the code - select it and type `ctrl-k`.
.. [Formatting help](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)... [Formatting sandbox](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3122/formatting-sandbox)

Comment: Why isn't the `'trans_timestamp'` a [datetime Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/timeseries.html)?

Comment: Hi wwii thanks for pointing this out and editing it to community standards. Next question I'll be sure to add a mock dataset, and not add any screenshots. I have no clue about the datetime series, this is my first time hearing of them; and even still I have no clue how to convert the data in the column to it.

Comment: Did you explore the Time series functionality link to the Pandas User Guide that I put in my previous comment? If your going to be using Pandas in the future it would serve you well to spend plenty of time working your way through that [User Guide](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/index.html), starting at the beginning - 10 minutes to pandas .

Answer (score 0):

The column `trans_timestamp` could be in string format instead of datetime object. Use `pd.to_datetime()` to convert to datetime format:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'trans_timestamp': ['2021-01-01 07:35:21.439','2021-01-01 09:33:37.499','2021-06-30 15:37:12.821'],
                   'prod_price': ['72.99','18.96','9.95']  })
df['trans_timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['trans_timestamp'])
print(df)

          trans_timestamp prod_price
0 2021-01-01 07:35:21.439      72.99
1 2021-01-01 09:33:37.499      18.96
2 2021-06-30 15:37:12.821       9.95
```

To check if the column is in datatime format, use `df['trans_timestamp'].info()`, you'd get `datetime64[ns]`. Then you can use `.min()` to get the smallest date

```
print(df['trans_timestamp'].min())
#output: Timestamp('2021-01-01 07:35:21.439000')

ts = df['trans_timestamp'].min()
first_date = (ts.month, ts.day)
print(first_date)
#output: (1, 1)
```

Comment: That makes sense to me but when I plug it to my specific problem I get this outcome: Your answer has the type `<class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timestamps.Timestamp'>` for the `first_date` variable but we expected a `tuple`. Double check your code.

Comment: try doing `first_date = (ts.month, ts.day)` where `ts = df['trans_timestamp'].min()`, see updated solution

Comment: is your question resolved?